# Prevent images loading of images for users with javascript enabled

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I got myself in some kind of chicken-egg situation here.
I have a page with a lot of images to load and i programmed a load on scroll script, like Facebook or Google images does, so when the user gets to the bottom of the page, the next set of images is loaded.

Because the server side images loading is kinda heavy and would probably slow down the website, i just load and store all images in a cache file, load it into the page and then with javascript, i remove all of them keeping only the first few and then gradually load the rest of them.

Now the first problem i ran into is that the browser keeps loading images even if they have been deleted using javascript. To get around it, i added a css class to the images i don't wan't to load and set them as display none, which i then remove using javascript.

But i still wan't the page to be non-javascript users and crawslers to be able to see the full page. And can't figure out a way to remove this "display none" without javascript.

Thank's in advance.

Comment: So, what's your actual code? We can't help / fix what we can't see.

Comment: Browsers tend to be pretty aggressive about loading image URLs they find in `<img>` tags, whether or not the elements are visible. It *might* work to put your no-JS markup in `<noscript>` tags, but maybe not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply use ajax to load the next batch?
That way it gets loaded into segments, load is spread and you don't need to do difficult markups...

My own jquery example of what I use in these kind of cases.
I have a php file that decides what needs to be rendering on basis of the "pagenumber" which gets translated in my mysql `select ..... limit $pagenumber,15`

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
    alreadyloading = false;
    nextpage = 1;

    $(window).scroll(function() 
        {
        if ($('body').height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) 
            {
            if (alreadyloading == false) 
                {
                var url = document.location.href + "/ajaxload/" + (nextpage * 15);
                alreadyloading = true;
                $.ajax(url).done(function(data) 
                    {
                    obj = document.getElementById('images');
                    obj.innerHTML += data;
                    alreadyloading = false;
                    nextpage++;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hello,
I actually do use ajax to load the next batch, but i first load the full thing. What my script does is :
1) Load the full cache file.
2) Delete the unused images delete javascript
3) Reload a set of images in the cache file on demand when scrolling.

But i wan't to be able to show all of them on a single page for users without javascript and search engine crawlers.

Comment: This is very simple. Use the noscript tag for the full page for bots etc...
That's the way it's supposed to be done. Browsers with javascript enabled ignore everything within the noscript tag.

Easy way to test: Google chrome, right click inspect element. Click the network panel and keep that open. Then load your page without ajax and all images in noscript tag. Not a single image should load. If this is confirmed, just put a noscript tag in. If not, come back then I'll help thinking.

Comment: Hi,
I guess i could make something out of this, i'll give it some more thinking tomorrow. Thanks.